# How do I use dash dcc.Upload and dcc.Store on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, plotly-dash

I have recently published a webapp to Heroku built using the Plotly Dash libary. The webapp is dependent on uploading files using Dash Core Components (dcc) `dcc.Upload` and then saving the files using `dcc.Store`. This works perfectly on the localhost, however, when trying to upload files to the live version hosted by Heroku, the `app.callback` depending on the uploaded files won't fire.

1. Is there any issues with using `dcc.Upload` or `dcc.Store`on Heroku? I haven't found any related issues on forums. The files are not large (< 1 MB), and as I said, it all works on the localhost.
2. Since it's not on my localhost I'm having problems with troubleshooting. Is there any easy way to troubleshoot a live webapp on Heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I found that the abrupt shortcoming of the callbacks were due to a timeout error with the code **H12** from Heroku. **H12** states that any call without a response wilthin 30 seconds is terminated. The solution was therefore to reduce the callbacks into smaller components so that no function exceeded the 30 second limit.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the user through which your app is running do not have write permissions to the directory in which you are saving the file after upload.

Try checking the permissions on the directory. If still not working, please share the errors you are getting. That would be easier to share solutions.